# Анимация CSS , как сделать анимацию

Tags: css3, css-animation

Я хочу сделать анимацию которая изменяет высоту блока с 100px до 700px , все получилось но есть проблема . Анимация проигрывается а потом высота приходит в начальное положение , как сделать что бы анимация останавливалась на высоте 700px пока не отведешь мышку от блока

Comment: Добавляйте же код к вопросам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если стоит задача всего лишь менять по наведению высоту блока, для этого не нужна анимация - просто добавьте блоку свойство transition:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border :1px solid red;
  transition: 1s;
}
div:hover {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать при помощи свойства [transition](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transition)

```js
$('.add').on('click', () => {
  $('.add').remove();
  $('.block').addClass('anim');
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height linear 1s;
}

.anim {
  background: green;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
<input type="button" class="add" value="анимация">
```

Можно при помощи [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy)

```js
$('.add').on('click', () => {
  $('.add').remove();
  $('.block').addClass('anim');
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.anim {
  background: green;
  animation: NewHeight linear 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes NewHeight {
  to {
    height: 700px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes NewHeight {
  to {
    height: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
<input type="button" class="add" value="анимация">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, по описанию похоже, что надо делать `transition`, а не `animation`.

Но если надо использовать именно `animation`, то там есть параметр `animation-fill-mode`, который можно выставить значение `both`.